# characterizations of the positive measures of Jordan decomposition theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\nu$ is a real measure on a measurable space $(X, S)$. Prove that $\nu^{+}(E) = \sup \{ \nu(D) : D \in S \text{ and } D \subset E\}$ and $\nu^{-}(E) = -\inf \{ \nu(D) : D \in S \text{ and } D \subset E \}$

I think Jordan Decomposition Theorem is the starting point here as $\nu^{+}$ and $\nu^{-}$ are singular.

Comment: Where you wrote $\nu^{+}(E) = \sup \{ \nu(D) : D \in S \text{ and } D \in E\},$ I wonder whether you meant $\nu^{+}(E) = \sup \{ \nu(D) : D \in S \text{ and } D \subseteq E\}. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, you are right, I will update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using notation from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem we have: $$\nu^+(E):=\nu(E\cap P)\text{ and } \nu^-(E):=\nu(E\cap N)\text{ and } \nu=\nu^+-\nu^-.$$
As $E\cap P\subset E $ we have $$\nu^+(E)=\nu(E\cap P)\leq\sup\{\nu(D\cap E):D\in S\}= \sup\{\nu(D):D\in S, D\subset E\}.$$

On the other hand, $$\nu(D\cap E)=\nu^+(D\cap E)-\nu^-(D\cap E)\leq \nu^+(D\cap E)\leq \nu^+(D\cap E)+\nu^+(D^c\cap E)=\nu^+(E)$$ Hence, $$\sup\{\nu(D\cap E):D\in S\}\leq \nu^+(E).$$ So altogether we have, $\sup\{\nu(D\cap E):D\in S\} = \nu^+(E)$.

Comment: O Raghaillaigh. Thank you! Can I define $\mu = - \nu^{-}$ and apply it the first part to conclude the second one?

Comment: Define $\mu=-\nu$ and notice $\mu^+=\nu^- $

Comment: O Raghaillaigh. Thank you very much!